# jquery get id of input selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several `input` fields (sometimes disabled). When the user clicks a button, how can I get the `id` of the `input` field that has text *selected* in it?

```
Text:<input type="text" id="myID" disabled="disabled" value="Hello World"/>
<input type="text" id="myID2" value="Hello again"/>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Get Selected Id" name="Get Selected Id"/>

$("#myButton").click(function(){
    alert(/*...how do I get 'myID' or 'myID2' here, depending on which has a selection?...*/);
});
```

By "selected" I mean like this:

[image]

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39x0cc6d/2/)

Unfortunately, I need to support not just modern browsers, but also IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

In IE you can successfully do this:

```
var id = document.selection.createRange().parentElement().id
```

Like this:

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function () {
  var node = document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
  if (node && node.id) {
     window.console && console.log("node_ " + node.id)
  }
});
```

in Chrome it seems to be trickier.

I have a solution which you may be able to use. It will break if there are more than one field with the same value

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/s9ms3eea/)

```
$(document).on("mouseup", "input", function () {
    var node = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().parentElement() : window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
    if (!node.id) {
        var sel = window.getSelection().toString();
        $("input").each(function () {
            if (this.value.indexOf(sel) != -1) {
                node = this;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    window.console && console.log("node:" + node.id)
});
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need...
I edited your fiddle to show the difference operating with several fields: http://jsfiddle.net/s9ms3eea/13/
As you said, it doesn't work on chrome but that's enough on IE8!